# Problems uploading Thumbnails of videos via the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

we are uploading videos to a page via the Facebook Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/videos

Now we are trying to upload thumbnails to videos as well via the "thumb" argument. We already have the ads_management permission.

The documentation says we should provide the binary thumbnail file as string.
So we tried the following approaches:
- We tried to send the image's bytes as string
- We tried to send the image as multipart/form-data (like the source)
Unfortunately none of these approaches worked.

Perhaps we have to encode the bytes in a certain way which is not mentioned in the docs (base64...)?

Comment: i too try some another facebook page video upload to my page. how u made upload with api ? can you share your script ?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to post it like you're submitting a file from a form.

Here's how it's done using Ruby, using httmultiparty:

```
include HTTMultiParty

video_url = "https://some_video_url.mp4"
picture_file =  File.new("some_local_file.png")

response = FacebookVideo.post("https://graph-video.facebook.com:443/your_page_id/videos", 
  :body => { 
    "access_token" => access_token,
    "file_url" => video_url,
    "thumb" => picture_file,
    "description" => "some awesome description"

  })
```

I dont think you need the ads_management permission, btw.